# recovering data from choregraphe project after a hard restart crash

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, crash, file-recovery

I am working with [Choregraphe](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/software/choregraphe/choregraphe_overview.html) to build some robot functionality in a project.

Recently I did something to cause my project to crash not only my Choregraphe, but also my entire system froze until I pulled the plug on it. Once I rebooted I tried to launch the project to fix the error in the project. Much to my surprise Choregraphe will crash to desktop on any attempts to open the project. Despite this no other projects were affected.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips or suggestions for recovering the project, as it has years of a former colleagues work that would be challenging to replace.

UPDATE:
So I figured out that my Behavior.xar file was overwritten by the crash with empty data. This is what is preventing me from opening the project. Is there a way to recover this file?